# get the data starting from 1st month till current date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, date-comparison, sysdate

I have written below query which is working fine and its getting the data everytime for every previous one week.

```
    select t.day_id 
    from F_TIME t 
    where t.day_id >= TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR( TRUNC ( SYSDATE , ''IW'' ) - 7 , ''YYYYMMDD'' )) 
                      and t.day_id <  TO_NUMBER ( TO_CHAR ( TRUNC ( SYSDATE , ''IW'' ), ''YYYYMMDD'' ))
```

But now i want to rewrite this query in such a way that it will always get data starting from 1st of month till sysdate. So for example if i run this query now i should get data from 1st January 2018 till 11th January 2018.

If i run this query on 1st Febrauary then it will return data for entire month of January.I am not sure whether its possible to do in single query.

The dayid is number datatype and in format for e.g 20170815

Comment: could you provide cte for sample data?

Comment: What datatype is `day_id`? Date, string, number? The answer will be different for each.

Comment: day_id is number datatype and data is stored in the format as 20040501

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specify your required date range more specifically.  If you run the query on `2018-01-11` what should be the first and last date included? If you run the query on `2018-03-30` what dates should be included (that last one is a trick question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the firts day of current month you can simply turn the first `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW')` to `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')` and turn `-7` to `-1` if you want data from preceeding month if run on first day of current month.

Then you want to get data till sysdate, so again turn the second `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW')` in `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`:

```
SELECT t.day_id 
  FROM F_TIME t 
 WHERE t.day_id >= TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR( TRUNC ( SYSDATE - 1 , 'MM' ) , 'YYYYMMDD' )) 
   AND t.day_id <= TO_NUMBER ( TO_CHAR ( TRUNC ( SYSDATE ), 'YYYYMMDD' ));
```

**EDIT:**

turned `<` to `<=` to get today.

in this way, if you run the query on 1st February you get entire January AND 1st February: if you want to exclude 1st February (i.e. today) you have to add a `CASE WHEN` statement.

Comment: When i run this query its giving the date from 1st January 2018 till 11.January 2018 and not till today i.e 12 January 2018. Also just want to confirm If i run this query on 1st Febrauary then should it return data for entire month of January ? If i run this query on 2nd Febraury then it should it return date for 1st of Febrauary and 2nd February ?

Comment: thanks its working now just want to know if i run the query on 2nd Febraury for e.g then it will return date from 1st Febrauary and 2nd February right and not for the month of January ? Only when i run this query on 1st February it will return the date for entire January and 1st February ?

Comment: Yes: running on 1st of current month you get entire previous month AND 1st of current month; running on any other day you get from 1st of current month till today

Answer (score 1):

I'm only familiar with MS SQL, I don't know much about Oracle. If I had to do this in MS SQL I'd end up working with today's date as text and modifying at as needed.

Here's a MS SQL compatible example.  Sorry that I have to leave it to you to convert it to Oracle, but hopefully the idea makes sense and there are equivalent functions in Oracle.

```
select CONCAT(DATEPART(month, GETDATE()),'/1/', DATEPART(year, GETDATE()))
```

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
select * from MyTable
where timestamp > CONCAT(DATEPART(month, GETDATE()),'/1/', DATEPART(year, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following with respect to your with day_id of `yyyymmdd` format :

```
   select day_id                  
     from F_TIME
    where to_date(day_id,'yyyymmdd') between to_date(to_char(sysdate,'yyyymm')||'01','yyyymmdd') and trunc(sysdate)
    order by to_date(day_id,'yyyymmdd')
```

[D e m o 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10bbf/11)

even if day_id is in numeric format(not string), above sql works, for this you may look at this :

[D e m o 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0889e0/1)

Comment: but how can i use this example in my table query. it looks bit complicated

Comment: what are the values of day_id ?

Comment: its in the format like for e.g 20170815..and i just run your query its returning too many dates. And is it not possible to restrict the query in where clause and not in select clause. Because i want to use this logic in many places for comparison

Comment: its returning null value and cant we write the logic in where clause and not in select clause ? Even if i get the data starting from 1st day of the month till current date then also its ok.

Comment: i am getting error as ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format. Please note day_id is number data type and its in format for e.g 20170815

Comment: really not understanding where the issue is coming. Is this the NLS setting or not sure but i am getting same error as ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format. I can see in your demo 2 its working properly. In question the query which i mentioned its working. I just check the issue in this link but not understanding: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01840_input_value_not_long_enough_for_date_format.htm

Comment: I think somewhere the conversion is failing

Comment: @Andrew i could get positive results from my db where NLS_DATE_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR, NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN, NLS_CALENDAR = GREGORIAN
, yours ..?

Comment: @Andrew What do you get when you issue : `select to_date(day_id,'yyyymmdd'), to_date('01'||to_char(sysdate,'.mm.yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy'), trunc(sysdate) from f_time;`

Comment: yes this query is running and i am getting different date values for the same

Comment: Is it possible to chane this running query according to the requirement ?

Comment: It suits requirement, since when you query these three statements in the select list, the first one remains between the second and the third values, as example : 1st 04.01.2018 between 2nd 01.01.2018 and 3rd 12.01.2018, 1st 05.01.2018 between 2nd 01.01.2018 and 3rd 12.01.2018 and so on ...( when i try in my db )

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle the expression `TRUNC(datestamp, 'MM')`  turns any datetime expression into midnight on the first day of its month.

If you had datestamps your date selection logic would look like this.

```
 WHERE datestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
```

gets you everything in the present month.

This gets you everything in the preceding month.

```
WHERE datestamp >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1)
  AND datestamp <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
```

Notice the use of `<` for the end of that time interval. You can't use `BETWEEN` for this sort of date range.

**EDIT** it looks like your `day_id`s are eight digit numbers `YYYYMMDD`. So, you need to convert your start and end dates to that format.

```
WHERE day_id>= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 'YYYYMMDD'))

WHERE day_id >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1), 'YYYYMMDD'))
  AND day_id <  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 'YYYYMMDD'))
```

**Pro tip**: Use the datetime data types furnished by your DBMS where possible. As you can see queries using those data types are much easier to read, and to [explain to your rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/), than other possibilities.

Comment: Shameless self promo: I wrote a blogpost on this topic. https://www.plumislandmedia.net/sql-time-processing/using-sql-report-time-intervals-oracle/

Comment: day_id is number datatype and data is stored in the format as 20170815 and for this reason i am getting error as inconsistent datatype

Comment: The query is running but its not giving the expected output. Its returning the data for full month of december 2017. Actually i want the result from 1st of month till current date everytime i.e for example from 1st of January till today. This is the first case and i think the second case will not get satisfied where for example If i run this query on 1st Febrauary then it should return data for entire month of January.If i run this query on 2nd Febraury then it should return date for 1st of Febrauary and 2nd February. I am not sure whether its possible to do this in single query

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first day of a month easily with the following strategy:

```
    SELECT 
        ADD_MONTHS( LAST_DAY ( TO_DATE('20220228', 'yyyymmdd') ) + 1, -1) AS "FIRST_DAY"
    FROM dual
```

Which returns:

```
        FIRST_DAY
    1   01/02/2022
```